# Ionic-native: Always same page title in Google Analytics

Tags: android, angular, google-analytics, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm trying to track my Ionic app with Google Analytics by using the `@ionic-native/google-analytics` package, but whenever I try to track a page view with this code:

```
constructor( //Constructor of each Page component
    ...
    public platform: Platform,
    public analytics: GoogleAnalytics
) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        analytics.trackView("Home Page");
    });
    ...
}
```

No matter which title I write on the first parameter of `trackView` I always get a `/` as Active Page (I guess this is because the actual URI doesn't change) and the same Page Title for every page I visit (the one I define at `index.html` title tag). I also tried without the `platform.ready()` wrapper, just in case, with no luck as well.

I already configured everything as said in [this guide](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin#example-use-ionic-2-ionic-native), so I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Any help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `analytics.trackView("Home Page");` will send an event to GA. Do you call this method on any of your other pages?

Comment: Yes, I call it on the constructor of each page but changing the title parameter, for example `analytics.trackView("Login Page")`. I detect the event in GA but the title does not change at all.